# How can I implement bxslider Thumbnail pager Next prev button

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, bxslider

**I am using bxslider and I am trying to Thumbnail pager next prev button to move thumbnails but I could not implement that can you help me sort out this one so I can implement thumbnail slider with thumbnail next prev buttons.**

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="1" width="960" height="600" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/1aNicollet.jpg" alt="1" width="960" height="600" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="1" width="960" height="600" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/100_2129.JPG" alt="1" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/408619_10151175168202229_1189668486_n.jpg" alt="1" width="960" height="600" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/134593849-jpg_215416.jpg" alt="1" width="960" height="600" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/beauty-dress-girl-photo-wallpaper-1920x1200.jpg" alt="1" width="960" height="600" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/meh.ro8908.jpg" alt="1" width="960" height="600" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/lilian-garcia-2011-05-02.jpg" alt="1" width="960" height="600" /></li>
</ul>

<div id="bx-pager">
     <a href="#" id="slider-prev">Previous</a>
     <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="images/thumb/1.jpg" alt="1" /></a>
     <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="images/thumb/1aNicollet.jpg" alt="1" /></a>
     <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="images/thumb/7.jpg" alt="1" /></a>
     <a data-slide-index="3" href=""><img src="images/thumb/100_2129.JPG" alt="1" /></a>
     <a data-slide-index="4" href=""><img src="images/thumb/408619_10151175168202229_1189668486_n.jpg" alt="1" /></a>
     <a data-slide-index="5" href=""><img src="images/thumb/134593849-jpg_215416.jpg" alt="1" /></a>
     <a data-slide-index="5" href=""><img src="images/thumb/beauty-dress-girl-photo-wallpaper-1920x1200.jpg" alt="1" /></a>
     <a href="#" id="slider-next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for a second previous/next action below the slider.

Call your slider as follows:

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
});

$('a.pager-prev').click(function () {
var current = slider.getCurrentSlide();
slider.goToPrevSlide(current) -1;
});
$('a.pager-next').click(function () {
var current = slider.getCurrentSlide();
slider.goToNextSlide(current) +1;
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/defonic/2cc7F/

Comment: But this does not slide pager. I want, it work like as carousel pager of slider.